# What is the correct way to hit the API in GetX?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, response, flutter-getx

I am using Getx `GetConnect()` to hit the API. But most of the time `GetConnect()` is not hitting  the API. I am not sure what is going wrong.

This is my code :

```
Response response = await GetConnect().post(
  apiBaseUrl + taskPathApi + getV2,
  {
    "query": {
      "tasker_id": kTaskerId,
      "task_status": [13],
      "tasker_availability": ["Checking", "Yes", "No"]
    },
    "display": {
      "perpage": 3,
      "pageno": pageNumber,
      "sorting_task": "start_asc"
    },
  },
  headers: {
    "accept-language": kLanguageCode.value,
  },
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  status = TaskList.fromJson(response.body).status;
  if (status) {
    totalCount = TaskList.fromJson(response.body).data.count;
    taskList.addAll(TaskList.fromJson(response.body).data.tasks);
    pageLoading = false.obs;
    refreshRequestedTask.loadComplete();
    update();
  }
} else {
  print("Something went wrong");
  refreshRequestedTask.loadComplete();
}
```

Is this the proper way to use `GetConnect()` ? or I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the full example of GetX API call example

https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_getx_example.git